# How to get the x (unknown) digit in a number made by writing natural numbers consecutively :123456789101112

Tags: c

I want to do this in C and I want to do it without using arrays or strings.

I have done it using arrays, but without it I do not know what to do. I am only allowed to use loops and if.

Comment: So what exactly is stopping you? You said you “have done it using arrays”, can you show us that code? Maybe there is a way to replace the arrays with something else. Are you sure the X will appear before you reach `ulong_max`?

Comment: you say you want to do it in c and this post is tagged c# not c.

Comment: Formatting, changed tag from c# to C

Comment: Please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, specifically the points about homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be an interesting problem and wrote the complete code for it. If you want to do it yourself, then don't look into the code. Here are some hints:
1. We know how many numbers of certain length there are:  `9 1-digit numbers, 90 2-digits, 900 3-digits and so on`
2. Thus, we can find out how long will be a number made of all 1, 2 and 3 -digit numbers written together: `9*1 + 90*2 + 900*3 = 2889`
3. That means that if we are asked to find 253673-th digit, we can say for sure that it's a digit from a 4-digit number, because `253673 > 38889` and `253673 < 488889`
4. Now we only need to find that 4-digit number and a digit inside of it.

---

Now, if you want just a solution, then here's my code, it's in C# though, but it should be really easy to translate if that's not a typo about C:

```
    public static int GetDigit(long digitPosition)
    {
        if (digitPosition < 10)
            return (int) digitPosition;

        int N = 1;
        long lengthOfNumber = 9;
        int amountOfDigits = -1;
        while(lengthOfNumber < digitPosition)
        {
            N++;
            // there are 9 one-digit numbers, 90 two-digit numbers, 900 three-digit numbers and so on
            int amountOfNumbers = 9 * (int)Math.Pow(10, N - 1);
            // length of all N-digit numbers written together
            amountOfDigits = amountOfNumbers * N;
            // total length of composed number if we add all N-digit numbers
            lengthOfNumber += amountOfDigits;
        }
        // now we know how much digits has the sub-number with target digit inside the composed number

        // shift target digit position by removing all numbers below N length
        // so if the digitPosition was 14, it will become 5th position in the number created from only 2-digit numbers, because we subtract all 9 1-digit numbers
        digitPosition -= lengthOfNumber - amountOfDigits;
        // get index of N-digit number that contains target digit, starting from the first N-digit number (for N=3 it's)
        long numberIndex = (digitPosition - 1) / N;
        // get index of digit inside that number, that is our target digit
        long digitIndex = (digitPosition - 1) % N;
        // find the number that contains target digit by adding index to the first N-digit number
        long targetNumber = 1 * (long)Math.Pow(10, N - 1) + numberIndex;
        // shift target digit to the target position
        for (int i = 0; i < N - digitIndex - 1; i++)
            targetNumber /= 10L;

        // digit found
        return (int) (targetNumber % 10L);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much.i will think on your hints first and try to write the code myself.

Comment: I read your answer and i have a problem;why did you subtract amountsofdigits from lengthofnumber after while?

Comment: And what is L in front of target number?

Comment: 10L means that it's `long` data type, so i don't have to cast it with (long). Without L it would be `int`.

Comment: `lengthOfNumber` is the total length of all the numbers written together, starting from 1, so if `N = 3` (we use 1-digit, 2-digit and 3-digit numbers), the number is `123456789101112...997998999`, total length of which is 2889.  
Now, `amountOfDigits` at that point contains the length of combined number for the last N, that is 3-digit numbers (`100101102...997998999`) `amountOfDigits = 900 * 3 = 2700`.  
  
_To be continued..._

Comment: So, total number length is 2889 and last 2700 digits of it belong to 3-digit numbers, that means that first `2889 - 2700 = 189` digits are the 1-digit and 2-digit numbers.  
Let's say that target `digitPosition = 2800`. It is the 2800-th digit starting from the first one, but if i subtract this 189 from it i will get `2611` - index to the digit starting not from 1, but from 100 - the first 3-digit number, it makes things easier, because now we have to find 2611-th digit in number `100101102103...997998999`.

Comment: Thanks very much but i wrote the code in code blocks and it didn't work

Comment: You must have missed something. I'm not sure this is a good place to discuss that though. You can ask another question about that specific code or send me an email to sergreeny@gmail.com, i'll look into it.

Comment: I've just installed Code::Blocks and successfully ran my code in C, the only changes were `Math.Pow` to `pow` (`#include <math.h>`) and `long` to `long long`.  
Here's pastebin with code on C: https://pastebin.com/6NSkHyq9

Comment: I will talk about it with you on gmail